# Linq-to-SQL complex custom object from SP

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq-to-SQL model that uses stored procs in some places to return the objects where more complex SQL is required. This all works fine.

I now need to return a custom object from an SP that also encapsulates a Linq-to-SQL object. For example, I have a class called `Employee` based on an `Employee` table. I also have a custom class called `rota` defined as follows:

```
public class rota
{
    public Employee employee{ get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartingTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime FinishTime { get; set; }
}
```

I have some fairly complex linq that calculates an employees rota for any given day and then returns that object. I want to move this logic to a stored procedure so I have total control over the sql (the generated sql is not great) however I am not sure how to return that object?

Comment: Why don't you just return the Employee PK column(s) in place of the employee complext type and just have a standard anonymous type coming back from the procedure via LINQ to SQL? You could then manually populate the full Employee via a second query that returned employees and manually merge the two. It would only be a few lines of code.

Comment: @JohnOpincar - in this case this was what I did, thanks.  However if I had a large number of results this would probably not be the way I went about it, do you know if it is possible to achieve what I was asking?  Either way, if you post an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work although I have not run it.  If this does not, I know you could do this with a SQL function that returned a table variable.

```
from x in dataContext.StoredProc("", "", "")
select new Rota {
    DisplayOrder = x.DisplayOrder,
    StartingTime = x.StartingTime,
    FinishTime = x.FinishTime,
    Employee = new Employee {
        EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId,
        Name = x.EmployeeName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a constructor for the Rota object that takes the sproc result as a parameter... that way you can do

```
.Select(x => new Rota(x)).ToList<Rota>();
```